# MAX-3SAT: Best data structure

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, conjunctive-normal-form

I am implementing a MAX-3SAT solver in C. Obviously, there is a lot of literature regarding boolean formulae in conjunctive normal form. I was planning to store them in the format:

```
int **formulae;
```

Which is an array of arrays of variable IDs, where the variable is negative to indicate negation (just as in the standard DIMACS CNF format).

Here is my question: are there any "clever" data structures for 3SAT I should know about? Perhaps structures that enhance the performance of solving algorithms?

Comment: Mate Soos, inventor of [CryptoMinisat](https://github.com/msoos/cryptominisat) wrote a post on the [memory layout for CNF clauses](https://www.msoos.org/tag/memory-layout/) which should be a relevant reading. It is probably instructive to study the source of leading SAT solvers before embarking on your own design.